# Right Stack Exchange site for questions about the computer industry business model

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I can't find any Stack Exchange site where to ask questions about open-source in general.

I need to write a paper that explains the historical developments of open-source in a professional and legal way. Therefore it would be interesting to find some publications about experiences companies have had with open-source. I've been to FOSDEM where some companies present a positive viewpoint about open-source. A paper however is only objective if it gives a balanced view about several opinions. Does anyone know any publications about this topic, or a Stack Exchange site where I can ask this question?

So to make a long story short: are there some pointers to publications with a negative view on Open-source?

Comment: Please post the question within your question as if it was on an SE site.

Answer (score 3):

The QA format provided by the SE platform is not a good fit for the kind of question that you want to ask.  Regardless of where you ask it, it will get closed as Not Constructive:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers
>   to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this
>   question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or
>   extended discussion

If you're looking for links to publications, Google is probably your best tool.

Comment: It's not realy an opinion I'm asking, it are references to opinions I am looking for. But I agree it has some characteristics that are open and do not fit in the Q&A format.

Comment: Even better than regular ol' Google, I'd turn to [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) for links to publications.

Comment: The problem is that most of the searches turn out to be "The success of open-souce", "learn from open-source software", etc. Personally I'm a huge fan of open-source. But it would not be academic to only present one viewpoint.

Comment: Try [this Google Search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=disadvantages+of+open+source&oq=disadvantages+of+open+source)

Comment: @Commu: I think you're making this problem a *bit* more difficult than it needs to be. For example, if I type `negatives of open source` into a regular Google search, the first couple of hits are pretty promising-looking: http://www.neilgunton.com/doc/?doc_id=8586 and http://winter1008opensource.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/positives-and-negatives-of-open-source-software/. They might not be sources you want to cite *directly* in an academic essay, but they can certainly give you some ideas on a direction in which to take your assessment.