# On which Stack Exchange Q&A sites can I ask about business side of cloud computing?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask about business side of cloud computing - trends, business models etc. Which Stack Exchange Q&A site should I go to?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your question(s)? They are pretty vague.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117646/where-can-i-ask-questions-on-cloud-computing or probably http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126400/right-stack-exchange-site-for-questions-about-the-computer-industry-business-mod